Test containers with node js running in github actions
I have nest js project, which uses tests containers for tests, I mainly need PSQL so I only run a single container for postgresql, works locally not in the CI pipeline, here is the TS code for setting it up
export const setupPostgresqlContainer = async () => {
  // Start a PostgreSQL container
  const postgresContainer = await new GenericContainer('postgis/postgis:16-3.4-alpine')
    .withEnvironment({
      POSTGRES_USER: 'test_user',
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'test_password',
      POSTGRES_DB: 'test_db',
    })
    .withStartupTimeout(100000)
    .withExposedPorts(5432) // Expose PostgreSQL port
    .start();

  return postgresContainer;
};

export const getPostgresqlContainerURL = (container: StartedTestContainer) => {
  const mappedPort = container.getMappedPort(5432);
  const host = container.getHost();

  const databaseUrl = `postgresql://test_user:test_password@${host}:${mappedPort}/test_db`;

  console.log(`Test DB URL: ${databaseUrl}`);
  return databaseUrl;
};

export const runMigrations = async (dbUrl: string) => {
  await execSync('npx prisma migrate deploy', {
    env: {
      ...process.env,
      DATABASE_URL: dbUrl,
    },
  });
};

I mainly use the above functions to create the container run the migrations.
Here is an example for using it in a test suite
 dbContainer = await setupPostgresqlContainer();
    const dbUrl = getPostgresqlContainerURL(dbContainer);
    await runMigrations(dbUrl);

    prismaService = new PrismaService(dbUrl);

    moduleFixture = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    })
      .overrideProvider(PrismaService)
      .useValue(prismaService)
      .compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();

Incase you want to check the prisma class it's simply a wrapper on top of prisma
import { Injectable, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

@Injectable()
export class PrismaService extends PrismaClient implements OnModuleInit {
  constructor(url: string) {
    super({ datasources: { db: { url } } });
  }

  async onModuleInit() {
    await this.$connect();
  }
}

Locally this all works fine, on CI (specifically git hub actions it does not) it does not.
A sample of the error
 PrismaClientInitializationError: Can't reach database server at `localhost:5438`
    Please make sure your database server is running at `localhost:5438`.
       9 |
      10 |   async onModuleInit() {
    > 11 |     await this.$connect();
         |     ^
      12 |   }
      13 | }
      14 |
      at t (node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:112:2488)
      at async Proxy.onModuleInit (src/prisma/prisma.service.ts:11:5)
          at async Promise.all (index 0)
      at async callModuleInitHook (node_modules/@nestjs/core/hooks/on-module-init.hook.js:43:5)
      at async Proxy.callInitHook (node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application-context.js:234:13)
      at async Proxy.init (node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.js:100:9)
      at async Object.<anonymous> (src/identification/identification.e2e.ts:95:5)

Any ideas ? I know git hub action runners come preconfigured with Docker, and I think the container works fine, the connect function for prisma doesn't throw any errors and the migration works fine
